# Using foreign doesn't work properly but when I restart the visual studio it works

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

Everytime I input new employee job details then submit the program at the very start of the program the foreign key ID  which is the personalInfo_id is correct, but right after  I go back to the dashboard  and then add a new employee again (without stopping the program) the foreign key ID doesn't add and still the same with the previous ID.
This is my code: I have 3 registration forms. Personal Information form,Job Details Form, and Requirements form. In personal Information and Job Details Form I only use proceed button, while in Requirements form I used submit button to finally insert all of the details

```
     public partial class Requirements : Form
    {
        public Requirements()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            showID();
        }
        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=hr_ms; SSL Mode=none");
        MySqlCommand command;
        MySqlDataAdapter DA;
        DataTable dt;


        public void clearRequirements()
        {
            tbSSS.Text = "";
            tbPhilhealth.Text = "";
            tbTin.Text = "";
        }
        public void showID()
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                string showid_query = "select personalInfo_id from tbl_personal_info ORDER BY personalInfo_id DESC ";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(showid_query, cn);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
                int number = id + 1;
                lblID.Text = number.ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Query was not executed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

private void pbBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dgResult = MessageBox.Show("Information will not save. Are you sure you want to go back? ", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            if (dgResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
               
                Program.JobDetails.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                Program.JobDetails.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Going back to form", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dgResult = MessageBox.Show("All information are correct?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dgResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (tbSSS.Text == "" || tbPhilhealth.Text == "" || tbTin.Text == "")
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Incomplete";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Complete";
                }
                HRProcess process = new HRProcess();

                process.insertPersonalInfoTable(lblReqtoJDtoPI_name.Text, lblReqtoJDtoPI_bod.Text, lblReqtoJDtoPI_address.Text, lblReqtoJDtoPI_number.Text, lblReqtoJDtoPI_email.Text, lblReqtoJDtoPI_marital.Text, lblReqtoJDtoPI_gender.Text);
                process.insertJobDetailsInfoTable(lblJD_pid.Text, lblJD_dept.Text, lblJD_jobTitle.Text, lblJD_salary.Text, lblJD_hired.Text, lblJD_tenure.Text, lblJD_contract.Text, lblJD_status.Text, lblJD_supervisor.Text, lblJD_jobDesc.Text, lblJD_position.Text);
                process.insertRequirementsTable(lblID.Text, tbSSS.Text, tbPhilhealth.Text, tbTin.Text, lblStatus.Text);

                MessageBox.Show("Information Added", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                Program.JobDetails.clearJobDetails();
                clearRequirements();
                Dashboard F2 = new Dashboard();
                F2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                F2.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Going back to form", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

        }
```

Comment: You must NOT calculate the next `tbl_personal_info.personalInfo_id`. You must insert into this table than retrieve generated `id` value and use it in the next queries which saves the data into another tables. Calculated value can be shown only as "predicted" `id` value, and actual value assigned during the insertion may differ.